# Query same thing in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table where there are some scores for pairs.

Like this

```
P1    P2    Score   Date
John  Mark  43      2011-01-01
Sinan Ash   53      2011-02-03
...
John  Suzie 34      2011-10-10
Ash   Sinan 54      2011-11-11
sinan suzie 42      2011-12-12
...
```

So what I want is to get all the scores for Sinan and his partner. 
What I am trying to get is something llike:

```
partner - score
ash       53
ash       54
suzie     42
```

I'm trying to do it with te query below. Is there a better way to query than

```
select * from table WHERE P1 = 'sinan' OR P2 = 'sinan'
```

Is this efficient? Maybe there is a better way to store the data in the first place.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How large is the data table?  That is probably the *simplest* method, even though it's technically not normalized.  Unless you need really high performance, I wouldn't bother optimizing it any more.

Comment: it's around 600000 and 800000 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real trick is alternating the partner between P1 and P2. The simplest approach might be:

```
SELECT P2 AS partner, Score
    FROM table
    WHERE P1 = 'sinan'
UNION ALL
SELECT P1 AS partner, Score
    FROM table
    WHERE P2 = 'sinan'
```

Comment: Do you think a case statement with the OR clause would perform better than a union? `select case when p1='sinan' then p2 else p1 end as partner from table where p1='sinan' or p2='sinan'`

Comment: @Derek: That's a good suggestion too. I was actually going to add it as an alternative option when your comment came in. I'd suggest benchmarking both.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the CASE statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN P1 = 'Sinan' THEN P2 ELSE P1 END AS Partner, Score
FROM ScoreTable
WHERE P1 = 'Sinan' OR P2 = 'Sinan'
```